# How to merge data in multiple rows to one row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to merge data in multiple rows to one row in SQL Server using with FOR XML PATH, but same it's not work .I try with

[image]

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + ZZ.UNAME FROM X XX 
    INNER JOIN Y YY ON YY.UUID = XX.UUID
    INNER JOIN Z ZZ ON ZZ.UID = YY.UID
    WHERE XX.TID = 'T1'
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [MERGE_NAME]
```

As result same

```
MERGE_NAME
ABC,XYZ
```

Can you tell me some mistakes or something wrong in here ? Thank you

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @merge_name VARCHAR(1000) = ''
SELECT @merge_name = @merge_name + ',' + ZZ.UNAME FROM X XX 
                                    INNER JOIN Y YY ON YY.UUID = XX.UUID
                                    INNER JOIN Z ZZ ON ZZ.UID = YY.UID
                                    WHERE XX.TID = 'T1'
SELECT RIGHT(@merge_name, LEN(@merge_name)-1)
```

If you use STUFF, you can try:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ZZ.UNAME
                              FROM X XX 
                                 INNER JOIN Y YY ON YY.UUID = XX.UUID
                                 INNER JOIN Z ZZ ON ZZ.UID = YY.UID
                              WHERE XX.TID = 'T1' FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,''), '<Name>', ''), '</Name>', ',')
```